# Issue with Quantity +/- Options in addtocart.phtml - Product Details Page

Tags: magento2, porto

I'm facing an issue with the product details page (addtocart.phtml) on my Magento website. The page is not displaying the Quantity +/- options, and I'm unable to add products to the cart using the regular interface.

I have checked the template file addtocart.phtml and verified that the relevant code for the Quantity +/- options is present. However, when I visit the product details page, the Quantity field is missing, and I can't figure out why.

Steps I've taken so far:

```
Verified that the addtocart.phtml file contains the correct code for the Quantity options.
Cleared the cache and re-indexed the Magento store.
Checked for any custom JavaScript or CSS that might be affecting the Quantity options.
Ensured that the product has a stock quantity greater than zero and is enabled for sale.
Looked for any layout XML updates that might affect the product details page.
```

Expected Result:
The Quantity +/- options should be displayed on the product details page, allowing customers to adjust the quantity before adding products to the cart.

Actual Result:
The Quantity +/- options are missing, and customers can't set the desired quantity for adding products to the cart.

Custom Theme: Porto 4.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Enble template path hints to verify which `phtml` file calling on the page.

> Go to Admin Panel -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Advanced
> -> Developer -> Debug

Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront  -> Yes

Enable Hints for Storefront with URL Parameter -> Yes

clear magento cache

Add this `?templatehints=magento` in URL like `exmaple.com/product.html?templatehints=magento`